# DataType.Time Attribute on ViewModel ignored by Telerik MVC Grid Filters

Tags: datetime, filtering, telerik-mvc

I have a ViewModel property decorated with the

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
```

The grid column is described thus:

```
columns.Bound(m => m.ArrivalTime).Width(130).Format("{0:hh:mm tt}");
```

The Telerik MVC Grid's edit mode detects the datatype as intended and provides only time values via drop-down. Good!

The bad news is that the filtering menu ignores the datatype specification and instead provides a datepicker control. Needless to say this prohibits filtering on the column.

Comment: you should post on the Tererik forum. Might get better response there.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik mvc grid not support time only picker as we can see in method

```
createTypeSpecificInput
```

file telerik.grid.filtering.js. So you can write your own tile filter input plugin... or try this [code](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-filter-ui.aspx)